# WSL2 is broken after minikube was installed

Tags: 20.04, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After I finished the completed guide of minikube installation on my WSL2. I'm getting the following error message when I try to open a new terminal `/usr/sbin/enter-systemd-namespace: line 10: /usr/sbin/daemonize: No such file or directory.`

The guide I used to install minkube is the one that provides [kubernetes io](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/).

Here the content of /usr/sbin/enter-systemd-namespace

```
#!/bin/bash

SYSTEMD_PID=$(ps -ef | grep '/lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target$' | grep -v unshare | awk '{print $2}')
if [ -z "$SYSTEMD_PID" ] || [ "$SYSTEMD_PID" != "1" ]; then
    export PRE_NAMESPACE_PATH="$PATH"
    (set -o posix; set) | \
        grep -v "^BASH" | \
        grep -v "^DIRSTACK=" | \
        grep -v "^EUID=" | \
        grep -v "^GROUPS=" | \
        grep -v "^HOME=" | \
        grep -v "^HOSTNAME=" | \
        grep -v "^HOSTTYPE=" | \
        grep -v "^IFS='.*"$'\n'"'" | \
        grep -v "^LANG=" | \
        grep -v "^LOGNAME=" | \
        grep -v "^MACHTYPE=" | \
        grep -v "^NAME=" | \
        grep -v "^OPTERR=" | \
        grep -v "^OPTIND=" | \
        grep -v "^OSTYPE=" | \
        grep -v "^PIPESTATUS=" | \
        grep -v "^POSIXLY_CORRECT=" | \
        grep -v "^PPID=" | \
        grep -v "^PS1=" | \
        grep -v "^PS4=" | \
        grep -v "^SHELL=" | \
        grep -v "^SHELLOPTS=" | \
        grep -v "^SHLVL=" | \
        grep -v "^SYSTEMD_PID=" | \
        grep -v "^UID=" | \
        grep -v "^USER=" | \
        grep -v "^_=" | \
        cat - > "$HOME/.systemd-env"
    echo "PATH='$PATH'" >> "$HOME/.systemd-env"
    exec sudo /usr/sbin/enter-systemd-namespace "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING"
fi
if [ -n "$PRE_NAMESPACE_PATH" ]; then
    export PATH="$PRE_NAMESPACE_PATH"
fi
```

The other file you may want to take a look is /usr/sbin/enter-systemd-namespace.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$UID" != 0 ]; then
    echo "You need to run $0 through sudo"
    exit 1
fi

SYSTEMD_PID="$(ps -ef | grep '/lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target$' | grep -v unshare | awk '{print $2}')"
if [ -z "$SYSTEMD_PID" ]; then
    /usr/sbin/daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
    while [ -z "$SYSTEMD_PID" ]; do
        SYSTEMD_PID="$(ps -ef | grep '/lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target$' | grep -v unshare | awk '{print $2}')"
    done
fi

if [ -n "$SYSTEMD_PID" ] && [ "$SYSTEMD_PID" != "1" ]; then
    if [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" != "bash --login" ] && [ "$1" != "/bin/bash --login" ]; then
        exec /usr/bin/nsenter -t "$SYSTEMD_PID" -a \
            /usr/bin/sudo -H -u "$SUDO_USER" \
            /bin/bash -c 'set -a; source "$HOME/.systemd-env"; set +a; exec bash -c '"$(printf "%q" "$@")"
    else
        exec /usr/bin/nsenter -t "$SYSTEMD_PID" -a \
            /bin/login -p -f "$SUDO_USER" \
            $(/bin/cat "$HOME/.systemd-env" | grep -v "^PATH=")
    fi
    echo "Existential crisis"
fi
```

Does anyone know how can i fix this?

Comment: Hello, just to update. When I finished the installation, I kept open the original terminal window. With that, I managed to comment the "source /usr/sbin/start-systemd-namespace" in the directoty "/etc/bash.bashrc". Then, I could opened new terminal windows without problem. When I check with the "which command" the source of this "daemonize", it appears to be on /usr/bin/daemonize, so I copied to /usr/sbin/daemonize. For now it works. But I still not sure if this the righ way to do this and I was lucky to have the orignal terminal window opened

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt-get install -y daemonize
```

Then change `/usr/sbin/daemonize` to `/usr/bin/daemonize`